# Resample polygon coordinates to space them evenly

Tags: python, polygon

I've a polygon like this:

[image]

The vertices are ordered correctly (anti-clockwise, I think):

```
coords = [
    {x: 428.0, y: 273.0}, {x: 410.0, y: 335.0}, {x: 398.0, y: 350.0}, {x: 384.0, y: 355.0}, {x: 363.0, y: 410.0},
    {x: 354.0, y: 424.0}, {x: 318.0, y: 455.0}, {x: 299.0, y: 458.0}, {x: 284.0, y: 464.0}, {x: 250.0, y: 490.0},
    {x: 229.0, y: 492.0}, {x: 204.0, y: 484.0}, {x: 187.0, y: 469.0}, {x: 176.0, y: 449.0}, {x: 164.0, y: 435.0},
    {x: 144.0, y: 392.0}, {x: 132.0, y: 349.0}, {x: 122.0, y: 334.0}, {x: 120.0, y: 324.0}, {x: 121.0, y: 294.0},
    {x: 119.0, y: 274.0}, {x: 121.0, y: 264.0}, {x: 118.0, y: 249.0}, {x: 118.0, y: 224.0}, {x: 121.0, y: 209.0},
    {x: 130.0, y: 194.0}, {x: 138.0, y: 159.0}, {x: 147.0, y: 139.0}, {x: 155.0, y: 112.0}, {x: 170.0, y: 89.0},
    {x: 190.0, y: 67.0}, {x: 220.0, y: 54.0}, {x: 280.0, y: 47.0}, {x: 310.0, y: 55.0}, {x: 330.0, y: 56.0},
    {x: 345.0, y: 60.0}, {x: 355.0, y: 67.0}, {x: 367.0, y: 80.0}, {x: 375.0, y: 84.0}, {x: 382.0, y: 95.0},
    {x: 395.0, y: 106.0}, {x: 403.0, y: 120.0}, {x: 410.0, y: 151.0}, {x: 417.0, y: 210.0}, {x: 419.0, y: 215.0},
    {x: 425.0, y: 218.0}, {x: 431.0, y: 225.0}, {x: 430.0, y: 265.0},
]
```

I would like to resample those vertices to space them evenly. It could be probably done by re-interpolating the 2D vertices but that's not something I'm confortable with and I wonder if a library already does that before trying to reinvent the wheel. How could I do?

### EDIT

For example, with `n=15`, I get a set of coordinates which looks like this:

[image]

## EDIT 2

With @kaya3 solution, `n=128`:

[image]

Comment: "resample those vertices to space them evenly" - what exactly do you mean ? Could you add a picture of how the polygon should look like in the end ?

Comment: Sorry, I thougth it was clear enough. I will try to draw something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution: choose `k` evenly spaced points by dividing the total perimeter of the polygon by `k`, and linearly interpolating.

```py
import math

def distance(p, q):
    return math.hypot(q['x'] - p['x'], q['y'] - p['y'])

def lerp(p, q, t):
    return {
        'x': (1 - t) * p['x'] + t * q['x'],
        'y': (1 - t) * p['y'] + t * q['y']
    }

def resample_polygon(polygon, k):
    edges = list(zip(polygon, polygon[1:] + polygon[:1]))
    arc_length = sum(distance(p, q) for p, q in edges) / k
    result = [polygon[0]]
    t = 0
    for p, q in edges:
        d_t = distance(p, q) / arc_length
        while t + d_t >= len(result) < k:
            v = lerp(p, q, (len(result) - t) / d_t)
            result.append(v)
        t += d_t
    return result
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question looking for a way to resample a polygon in numpy array format.

Meanwhile, I solved the problem; maybe this is helpful for other people:

```
import numpy as np

def resample_polygon(xy: np.ndarray, n_points: int = 100) -> np.ndarray:
    # Cumulative Euclidean distance between successive polygon points.
    # This will be the "x" for interpolation
    d = np.cumsum(np.r_[0, np.sqrt((np.diff(xy, axis=0) ** 2).sum(axis=1))])

    # get linearly spaced points along the cumulative Euclidean distance
    d_sampled = np.linspace(0, d.max(), n_points)

    # interpolate x and y coordinates
    xy_interp = np.c_[
        np.interp(d_sampled, d, xy[:, 0]),
        np.interp(d_sampled, d, xy[:, 1]),
    ]
    
    return xy_interp
```

The function can be used like this for the provided data:

```
coords = [
    {'x': 428.0, 'y': 273.0}, {'x': 410.0, 'y': 335.0}, {'x': 398.0, 'y': 350.0}, {'x': 384.0, 'y': 355.0}, {'x': 363.0, 'y': 410.0},
    {'x': 354.0, 'y': 424.0}, {'x': 318.0, 'y': 455.0}, {'x': 299.0, 'y': 458.0}, {'x': 284.0, 'y': 464.0}, {'x': 250.0, 'y': 490.0},
    {'x': 229.0, 'y': 492.0}, {'x': 204.0, 'y': 484.0}, {'x': 187.0, 'y': 469.0}, {'x': 176.0, 'y': 449.0}, {'x': 164.0, 'y': 435.0},
    {'x': 144.0, 'y': 392.0}, {'x': 132.0, 'y': 349.0}, {'x': 122.0, 'y': 334.0}, {'x': 120.0, 'y': 324.0}, {'x': 121.0, 'y': 294.0},
    {'x': 119.0, 'y': 274.0}, {'x': 121.0, 'y': 264.0}, {'x': 118.0, 'y': 249.0}, {'x': 118.0, 'y': 224.0}, {'x': 121.0, 'y': 209.0},
    {'x': 130.0, 'y': 194.0}, {'x': 138.0, 'y': 159.0}, {'x': 147.0, 'y': 139.0}, {'x': 155.0, 'y': 112.0}, {'x': 170.0, 'y': 89.0},
    {'x': 190.0, 'y': 67.0}, {'x': 220.0, 'y': 54.0}, {'x': 280.0, 'y': 47.0}, {'x': 310.0, 'y': 55.0}, {'x': 330.0, 'y': 56.0},
    {'x': 345.0, 'y': 60.0}, {'x': 355.0, 'y': 67.0}, {'x': 367.0, 'y': 80.0}, {'x': 375.0, 'y': 84.0}, {'x': 382.0, 'y': 95.0},
    {'x': 395.0, 'y': 106.0}, {'x': 403.0, 'y': 120.0}, {'x': 410.0, 'y': 151.0}, {'x': 417.0, 'y': 210.0}, {'x': 419.0, 'y': 215.0},
    {'x': 425.0, 'y': 218.0}, {'x': 431.0, 'y': 225.0}, {'x': 430.0, 'y': 265.0},
]

# construct numpy array from list of dicts
xy = np.array([(c['x'], c['y']) for c in coords])

# resample polygon
xy_resampled = resample_polygon(xy, 100)

# plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,14))
ax.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], marker='o', s=150)
ax.scatter(xy_resampled[:, 0], xy_resampled[:, 1])
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]